# Show that if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$ increases on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

What technique needs to be used to integrate these type of functions?

Consider the function: $f(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$

Show that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ increases on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\exp(-t^2)$ is always positive

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $x < y$. Then, we have:
$$f(y) = \int_{0}^{y}e^{-t^{2}}dt = \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt + \overbrace{\int_{x}^{y}e^{-t^{2}}dt}^{\ge 0} \ge \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt = f(x) $$

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f(x)$ is $e^{-x^{2}}$ which is always positive. This well-known integral has no analytic expression.